# Serializable Isolation Violation Errors in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Recently we see a huge amount of errors that pertain to `Serializable isolation violation on table` we have some base tables that forms our core data and we extract values from these tables to run our business logic in Lambda's.

Scenario :

- Lambda 1 : Runs every 15 mins and gets the latest data from the source (RDBMS) into Redshift which forms our base tables (Does a `DELETE` and `INSERT`)
- Lambda 2 : Triggered after successful run of the above Lambda and this is where the business logic is written and is normal `SELECT` statements
- Lambda 3 : Triggered every 15 mins and is also run using the base tables and has only `SELECT` statements

When the Lambda 1 is triggered for its next run at instances we see that it fails with the `Serializable isolation violation` error.

Based on most of the posts putting a LOCK on the table might solve the issue but will increase the wait time for the other queries to run longer than expected and due to the constraint of the Lambda it will timeout after 15 mins which is not ideal. And I did see posts that stated putting a LOCK didn't entirely solve it too so skeptical to use to.

So something that struck me is would creating a `VIEW` on top of the base table and use the view in all the SELECT statements would that help here, if someone has any insights on this would really be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is with the locks each transaction is creating and being unable to determine the correct order the locks need to be resolved in.  See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-serializable-isolation/

Now your description doesn't have enough writes in flight as stated to see how you are getting this from one pass of the Lambdas runs.  So either this description isn't complete (multiple Lambdas updating tables) or the issue is coming between runs of Lambdas.  A possibility is that the transaction aren't being closed and the Lambda invocations are having locks that cannot be resolved.  Do you have COMMITs closing transactions?  More info is needed to know which.

You can inspect pg_locks between Lambdas to see what locks are left around.  The XID is the transaction that has the lock.  I'd guess you have many more open transactions than you expect.  Are your Lambda sessions in autocommit mode? Are you updating tables from multiple sessions?  Are you COMMITting your changes?  Are you reusing scratch tables?

Adding an explicit LOCK to serialize things can work if you know why / what tables are causing the serialization issue.  This is also not likely the best solution and a better approach will likely be apparent when the issue is understood.

Adding a view to the mix won't resolve the issue (though it might move it if it changes the timing of events).

Comment: Commit -> There is a commit in each Lambda thats done.
Table Update -> No only a Single Lambda does the Update and Delete to the Table (There is a Vaccum Job but that runs only once a day which makes it not a suspect)
Scratch Tables if you mean to ask the base data tables yes they are used in almost all parts of the other lambda's as they are our source of data.
Sorry for the delay in response

Comment: So not being able to see all the code and sequence of activities it is hard to know exactly what is going on.   The link provided is good for understanding the basic issue here.  What I expect is one Lambda is reading table A and changing table B while another is reading table B and changing A.  If these overlap with the right timing you have the dependency loop they are describing.  Is this possibly what is happening?