# Using LOCK to prevent serializable isolation issue in Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have a Python script that selects from a customer table then insert it into another table.

```
# coding: utf-8
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from provider import post
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
from utils import get_env
import constants

from utils import get_env, measure_runtime, raise_message, pprint, retry
from error_report import report, get_logger

db_url = get_env('conn_redshift')
conn = psycopg2.connect(db_url)
cur = conn.cursor()

@retry()
@raise_message("Unable to insert tuple to stripe customers")
def insert_tuple(cur, account, dictionary):
    cur.execute(
        begin;
        lock {0}.customers;

        sql.SQL("""
        SELECT id, created_at FROM {0}.customers WHERE stripe_id = (%s);
        """).format(sql.Identifier(account)), (dictionary['id'], ))

    conn.commit()

    customers = cur.fetchone()
    print(f" > update customers {dictionary['id']}")
    if customers and len(customers) == 2:
        (id, created_at) = customers
    else:
        id = str(uuid4())
        created_at = datetime.now().isoformat()

    cur.execute(
        

        """
            INSERT INTO stage_customers (
            stripe_id,
            name_1,
            name_2,
            address,
            postcode,
            city,
            country_id,
            updated_at,
            created_at,
            id
            ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """,
        (dictionary['id'], 
            dictionary['name_1'], dictionary['name_2'], dictionary['address'],
            dictionary['postcode'], dictionary['city'], dictionary['country_id'],
            dictionary['updated_at'], created_at, id))
    
    conn.commit()

@raise_message("Unable to import customers")
def import_customers(account, customers):
    if account != constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_CH and account != constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_DE:
        raise Exception('Unknown account -> ' + account)

    if customers:
        #db_url = get_env('conn_redshift')

        #conn = psycopg2.connect(db_url)
        #cur = conn.cursor()

        print(f"{account} customers import: start @ {datetime.now()}")

        cur.execute(
            sql.SQL("""
                CREATE temp TABLE stage_customers (LIKE {0}.customers)
                    """)
                        .format(sql.Identifier(account))
                    )
        conn.commit()

        for customer in customers:
            insert_tuple(cur, account, customers)

        cur.execute(
            sql.SQL("""
                DELETE FROM {0}.customers WHERE {0}.customers.stripe_id IN (SELECT stripe_id FROM stage_customers);
                    """)
                        .format(sql.Identifier(account))
                    )

        conn.commit()

        cur.execute(
            sql.SQL("""
                INSERT INTO {0}.customers SELECT * FROM stage_customers;
                """)
                    .format(sql.Identifier(account))
                    )
        
        conn.commit()

        cur.execute(
            sql.SQL("""
                DROP TABLE stage_customers;
                    """)
                    .format(sql.Identifier(account))
                   )

        conn.commit()
        
        print(f"{account} contact import: finished @ {datetime.now()}")



@measure_runtime
#@report(get_logger(channel="#dwh", app_name="Stripe Customers"))
def main():
    ch_stripe_customers = post(constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_CH, "/contact/search",
                            constants.PAYLOAD)
    de_stripe_customers = post(constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_DE, "/contact/search",
                            constants.PAYLOAD)

    import_customers(constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_CH, ch_stripe_customers)
    import_customers(constants.PUBLIC_STRIPE_DE, de_stripe_customers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

While running the Python script above, I receive the error:

```
Serializable isolation violation on table - 20123891, transactions forming the cycle are: 282075744, 238073135
```

Upon doing some research, Redshift recommends using LOCK to prevent this issue.

Could you please give an example how I can use the LOCK command in this Python script?
Or does psycopg2 probably provide a functionality to prevent this issue?

---Update--- 
If I try

```
BEGIN;
LOCK customers;

def insert_tuple(cur, account, dictionary):
        cur.execute(
            sql.SQL("""
            SELECT id, created_at FROM {0}.customers WHERE customer_id = (%s);
            """).format(sql.Identifier(account)), (dictionary['id'], ))
```

I got the error:

```
begin;
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Update:

Comment: Almost certainly Redshift doesn't recommend adding more locks when the problem was caused by too many locks in the first place. You still haven't found what the issue is, only the symptoms. Why did two transactions block each other? Which ones were they? Your question shows two tiny queries that seem to read a single line from one table and insert it into another. Are you executing this for every source row? That's *very* slow in every database but also *extremely* expensive in Redshift. Redshift was built to ingest 1M rows as fast as 1. Which means executing 1M inserts is *extremely* slow

Comment: What you seem to be doing is called RBAR in every database - Row By Agonizing Row. The reason it's extremely expensive in Redshift is that Redshift is a column-based database. Data is stored by column, not by row. For each column data is stored as a value and a list of all rows that use that value. This reduces storage and makes querying for specific values a lot faster. Each column is almost an index by itself.

Comment: When you insert a new row, the data of all columns needs to be updated. When inserting lots of rows, Redshift can update each column in parallel and use specialized algorithms to quickly insert the new values. The more data you have, the greater the parallelization benefits. When you insert the rows 1-by-1 though, you repeat the same process over and over again. Inserting 1M rows one by one may easily be over 1M times slower than just importing 1M rows with a single COPY

Comment: hi @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comment. Could you tell me why you can come up with the statement "when the problem was caused by too many locks in the first place" ? Afaik, there was not any lock there? 
I think they are the problems because these 2 scripts run at the same time with the same concurrent_xid, and both got aborted, having the same aborted_xid. 

I can update the code.

Comment: First, the error itself tells you that. Two transactions collided. Transactions use locks. Second, your own question shows *two* queries. I suspect this code is called in a loop which means there are a lot of tiny queries executed on a system that really hates small queries

Comment: your comment makes a lot of sense. Could you provide some link or hints how I can change the code to utilize Redshift's capability?

Comment: What *are* you doing in the first place? Are the tables in the same database? In that case an `INSERT ... SELECT` would combine and move data from the source tables to the target very quickly. For general loading from an external source though, exporting the data to a file on S3 and importing it with `COPY` is extremely fast. The Redshift docs describe various techniques that can be used to load large volumes of data, although in Redshift's case that means multi-GBs of data

Comment: I am actually a makeshift data engineer, so pardon me for the details. I have updated the question with the entire code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct but maybe I can add some info that can help.  First off it takes 2 connections to create a serialization error so the issue is between your code and some other connection to Redshift.  Or do you run multiple instances of this code at the same time?  The error message gives you the 2 xid’s so you can look up what these sessions are doing at the time.  I wrote this up for another user a couple of years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525123/serializable-isolation-violation-errors-in-amazon-redshift/64528627#64528627